# localizedStringForKey:value:table ignores Base localization

Tags: ios, localization

My application need to be localised in 2 languages: German and English. German should be Base language. It means that app should always localize to German except the language on device is english (in this case it should be on english)

I have custom *.string files for localisation and use localizedStringForKey:value:table to localise strings.

When I have only base localisation everything works fine. But in case if I add english localisation, in some reason localizedStringForKey:value:table just ignore Base localisation and always use English (for all languages)

Here how it looks like after I've added english:
[image]

and here is how I localise strings:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"key" value:@"" table:@"Shared"]
```

I'm testing on simulator and here is my language screen:
[image]

Does anybody know what could be a problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language is the device (or simulator) that you are testing on set to? Can you also include a screen shot of the language screen - the ordering on that screen is important :)

Comment: Also in your `Info.plist`, what is your `Localization native development region` ([`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey)) set to?

Comment: @Rich, I'm testing on simulator with German language. I also tried another languages but I always see english inside the app (not german witch is in Base localization).  included screen above :) In Info.plist Localization native development region is also German.

Comment: Oh :( That's not what I was hoping for. I have just noticed that `German` in the `Info.plist` is `de_DE`, any luck if you manually set this just to `de`, maybe the region is causing an issue.

Comment: @Rich setting "de" fixed the problem :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to set the `Localization native development region` ([`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey)) in the `Info.plist` to your language code. Xcode seems to set it to a `en_GB` or `de_DE` style region code, setting it to `de` (no region) will fix it. Note that by default it is `en`, but selecting `United Kingdom` or `Germany` will change it to use the longer codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution, I think it works for you:

```
NSString* NSCustomLocalizedString( NSString *key , NSString *comment)
{
NSString *rs = nil;

if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:KEY_LANGUAGE ] == e_language_japanese)
{
rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-ja",nil);
}
else
{
rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-en",nil);
}
return rs;
}
```